# issue in inflating layout

Tags: android, layout

I have a class a class showProduct which extends BaseAdapter. I am trying to infalte a layout in getView method but when i am taking ids(R.id.tvName) of views in the layout it do not takes the ids. I have set the ids in the layout.

```
class showProduct extends BaseAdapter{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return rows;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.show_product,null);
        TextView tvName,textViewDesc;

        tvName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you mean the "R.id.tvName" is underlined red like it wouldn't exist you could try to rebuilld your project. Sometimes this annoying thing happens.

Comment: Yes it works for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set `return convertView;` instead of `return null;` in `getView()`  
also in `getItem()` you should return something like `return items.get(position);`